# css How can I make the page body stay the same size even if I add element to it?

Tags: html, css

I have a page and I want to set up my body to 100% so it can't take the screen size and inside body there's a mainContainer div that weight and height are 90% of the body.

Now, Every time I tried to add a div (LoginInnerContainer) inside and want the div to 30% of the root div and in the middle, for some reason, the body gets longer and the inner container doesn't get in the middle .

Why is this happening and how I can I solve it, while keeping the body the size of the screen? Too bad I don't have enough reputation to post the picture to help understanding what I'm saying.

Here's my  HMTL code

```
<html>
          <head>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php URL?> public/css/default.css">
              <title></title>
           </head>
           <body>
             <div id="mainContainer">
                 <header>

                </header>

                     <div id="loginInnerContainer">
                          <div id="loginLogoContainer"></div>
                          <div id="loginFormContainer"></div>
                     </div>
            </body>
 </html>
```

and there's my CSS so far but the #loginInnerContainer get in the middle and the page gets longer than I need it.

```
#mainContainer { 
/*    height: 590px;*/
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 50px;

}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    background-image:url('../images/wood-dark.png');
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    display: block;

}
#loginMainContainer{
    height: 100%;
    padding:auto 0;
}

#loginInnerContainer{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    margin:auto 0 auto 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i would reset the margin and padding of the whole page:

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[More info](http://css-tricks.com/reset-all-margins-padding/). 
This way some default paddings and margins will be resetted.

Next thing is that you're using margin for your #loginInnerContainer. Margin is always outside the container, you want to use padding for this. More info [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-between-margins-padding-css/).

 Though the page will still be bigger as needed... 
This is because your padding will also extends the container. 
to exclude this you could use [`box-sizing`](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html).

 Now you can also set your width and height to 100% of the screen, without paying attention to the padding.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqycm/)**


Hope this helped you :)

Comment: Actually it helped me to understand what was going on but I actually used this

  #loginInnerContainer{
   
    background-color:blue;
    width: 90%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin:auto 0 ;
  
}